# Is there a way to programmatically refresh DNS cache on linux?

Tags: c++, linux

We have a large c++ application which will send data constantly from one server to another. We dynamically connect to a specific end point - some virtual IP address. If the IP address is unreachable, the resolved host is redirected to a different address, but that's all taking place on the destination server.

Us as the source server will need to refresh our DNS cache in order to recognize that our endpoint has changed.

Is there a way in c++ to programmatically refresh the DNS cache on a Linux box?

Answer (score 0):

have a look here and match the command you need to your system
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/

code will be

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
system("unix command goes here");
```